# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null - Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have some code that was working now it currently isn't even though the code hasn't changed. I am on a different computer now though.

I am getting an error about replacing a value with null though I have done some testing (console.log) and looks like nothing is coming back null. Below is the code as well as the error message. I did check the 'config' variable and it does have a value. I am wondering what this error means/what is causing it. I have tried google and found a few issues about it however none have a solution in them just a lot of "me too" responses.

Code

```
console.log(message)
axios.post(config.EXPRESS_URL, {
      content: message.content,
      abut_code: message.abut_code,
      media_url: '',
      userID: message.userID,
      name: message.name
}, {headers})
.then(() => {
      console.log('Message sent')
})
.catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
})
```

Error message/console output

```
{
  content: 'test',
  abut_code: 'bff1377f:d7de22eb',
  userID: 'auth0|613a9e709518390070831c29',
  name: 'Me 2'
}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at dispatchHttpRequest (/Users/me/projects/tenanttalk/backend/websocket/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:109:74)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at httpAdapter (/Users/me/projects/tenanttalk/backend/websocket/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:46:10)
    at dispatchRequest (/Users/me/projects/tenanttalk/backend/websocket/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:52:10)
```

Comment: No, it means something tried to read `somevalue.replace` but `somevalue` was `null`. The error was because it ended up trying to read `null.replace`, which, of course, isn't valid.

Comment: it looks like the error is in the backend side, I believe

Comment: @Ouroborus okay so what is null? That is the part that makes no sense, I can console.log all values and get an output.

Comment: @DanielSifontes Backside? Do you mean the API endpoint Axios is trying to reach? If so I don't think that is the case as I can use postman to test it and it works plus this Axios request never actually seems to hit the API server and is failing before it hits it

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error when the provided url was not correct (I forgot the "http://" in the url in my case) check `config.EXPRESS_URL` and make sure it's a valid url.

Comment: This answer solved my problem.  axios gives the error if the url is incorrect.